# What is the ideal size of images for Tensorflow object detection model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, object-detection

I am creating an object detection model using TFOD API.I have to detect a very small object in my image.What should be the ideal size of an image to feed into my model? Some of my images are very large.

Also I have already labelled some images. Can I resize these images also? Or I have to label them again?

Comment: If you have small objects, larger images are better. There is no limitation, but larger images, take more time to train. You only need to set the input size in the config file, and in this way, you don't need to relabel them.

Comment: Larger images throw an invalid SOS paramters error.

Comment: The SOS parameters, does your computer need some help from dangerous types?
There is no ideal size for me but objects need to compare to be similar and differentiated, adding 0.5 times side area from the sizes of the objects perform better or velocity.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the image recognition you do not expect them to have the 100% correct similar to the input image or VDO input but alignments or post positioning.

This is not the final result I do it for fun only but you see that 100% similar to the training inputs with small datasets is not provided accuracy as charm pictures.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
path_1 = "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Duck_Shoe_2\\Duck\\"

list_picture = []
list_actual_picture = []
list_label = []
list_actual_label = ['None', 'Duck']

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 29, 39, 3 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((234, 32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
])
        
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
for file in os.listdir( path_1 ):
    image = plt.imread( path_1 + file )
    list_actual_picture.append( image )
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [29, 39]).numpy()
    list_picture.append( image )
    list_label.append( 1 )
    
list_picture = tf.cast( list_picture, dtype=tf.int64 )
list_picture = tf.constant( list_picture, shape=( 6, 1, 29, 39, 3 ) )
list_label = tf.cast( list_label, dtype=tf.int64 )
list_label = tf.constant( list_label, shape=( 6, 1, 1, 1 ) )
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(( list_picture, list_label ))
list_picture = tf.constant( list_picture, shape=( 6, 29, 39, 3 ) )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=3 ,validation_data=(dataset))



plt.figure(figsize=(3,2))
plt.title("Actors recognitions")
for i in range(len(list_picture)):
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        list_picture[i],
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    plt.subplot(3, 2, i + 1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(list_actual_picture[i])
    plt.xlabel(str(round(score[tf.math.argmax(score).numpy()].numpy(), 2)) + ":" +  str(list_actual_label[tf.math.argmax(score)]))
    
plt.show()

input('...')
```

**[ Output ]:**

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goAuL.jpg)